# Differences between "We climbed high so that we might get a better view" and "We climbed high that we might get a better view"?

Tags: word-usage

Is there any differences between "We climbed high so that we might get a better view"
and "We climbed high that we might get a better view"? Is the second sentence informal?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference I am aware of between the two sentences. The first is the more usual version.

The second sentence sounds rather archaic to me. A google search for "that we might" reveals quite a few quotes from the bible, or Christian hymns. In particular, the hymn [He Died That We Might Live Again](https://www.lds.org/music/library/childrens-songbook/he-died-that-we-might-live-again?lang=eng), which has the same meaning as "He Died, so that we might live again".

I would avoid the second sentence, unless you are trying to write something that sounds either old-fashioned, or like a religious (particularly Judeo-Christian) text. Otherwise, use the first version.

Incidentally, you can remove the word "that" from the first sentence, to get a sentence which is slightly more informal.

Comment: I  agree about the archaism of the latter. I think that "that" makes the former sound more archaic, not more formal.